# Force download of a file from memory with support for downloading more than once

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I am dynamically generating a file from server based on user input. I need to provide a download button which, upon clicking, downloads a file to the user's file system.

Also, the user might click the same button twice, upon which the file should download again.

The dynamic generation of file rules out the HttpResponse.TransmitFile() option, which suports mutliple download.

Almost every other option I have come across needs Response.End() to be invoked, which prevents a second download.

How do I satisfy the 'multiple download" requirement?

Read up on Virtual Path providers, which might enable me to use TransmitFile(), but that looks like an overkill for such a simple requirement.

Comment: But TransmitFile doesn't allow browser to automatically detect type of file and open download dialog.

Comment: What do you mean "prevents a second download"?  You imply that the user clicks on the "same button twice".  Do you mean two separate clicks?  Because that would result in two separate HTTP requests, so combining them both in the same response seems nonsensical.

Comment: @Kirk Woll Yes, I am implying the user clicking the same button twice. No, I am not talking about combining two separate requests, just the same button again after the first download has finished. THe Response.End() just seems to kill the page and it doesnt respond.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer from here:

http://www.eggheadcafe.com/tutorials/aspnet/3889fc21-1562-4d1b-89e4-cea5576690b2/refresh-web-pages-after-d.aspx

Basically it uses a client side script to reload the page after a download:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    var isReload = false;
    function DownloadFiles()
    {
        if(isReload == true)
        {
            isReload = false;
            window.location.reload();     
        }
        else
        {
            isReload = true;
        }
        window.setTimeout("DownloadFiles()", 2000);
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblMsg"></asp:Label>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Download" OnClientClick="DownloadFiles();" OnClick="Button1_Click"/>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try either of the following:

1. Re-Generate the file each the user clicks download.
2. Save the file to disk, and stream it from there.